# Water from Rey to Kylo Ren... but how?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

During the scene where

> it's raining and Rey and Kylo Ren are Skyping/Snoking

it appears that water is

> transferred from where Rey is to where Kylo Ren is

How is this possible.  We see many cases of

> physical interaction over distance

but actual

> transfer of material?  Or was that simply a similar "illusion" and the "water" disappeared as the call ended?

Comment: This isn't exactly clear from the film and any answers will be speculative, this may require us to wait until the novelisations have been released (or until someone tweets Rian)

Comment: ...Space magic.

Comment: Neo, pulling fingers with blood on them from his mouth, after the sparring match with Morpheus. "I thought it wasn't real." "Your mind makes it real" says Morpheus.

Comment: Snoking... Haha

Comment: I assumed that the water was Ren's sweat.  Perhaps it wasn't physically transferred but was subconsciously formed from local moisture.

Answer (score 6):

We see at least one other item in the film that *appears* to be tangible (as a result of a Force connection)  but then disappears when the link between the two people is broken; [Han's lucky dice](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Han_Solo%27s_dice).

[image]

It seems likely that a few seconds after Kylo Ren felt the water on his face, it mysteriously vanished.

Comment: mmm - so it seems like it wasn't really water after all, but a projection of it.  Kind of like background noise in a phone conversation being transmitted.

Comment: There is a difference between the dice and the water.  The dice was completely fake - the water was actually teleported, like <MINOR SPOILER WARNING> Vader's helmet.

Answer (score 1):

From what we see in Episode Nine, where

> Rey's necklace is force-teleported to Kylo Ren, who then is able to have it analyzed without it disappearing,

It would seem that things that are force-teleported do not disappear, but rather stay. Otherwise, Kylo wouldn't have been able to

> have the necklace analyzed before it mysteriously disappeared. In fact, we see a First/Final Order officer holding the necklace when she reports to him after the analysis.

Most likely, I think that the water evaporated. It was only a few droplets, after all.